# Twitter bootstrap dropdown goes outside the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement twitter bootstrap dropdown menu, here's my code:

```
<span class="dropdown"> 
<a href="#menu1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img class="left" src="/static/img/topmenu_preferences.png" /><b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
</ul>
```

Dropdown works good, my dropdown is placed next to right edge of the screen and when I click my dropdown-toggle, the list goes outside the screen. It looks like on the screen:

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: The correct answer (for bootstrap >= v 3.2.0) to this question is resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654962/keep-bootstrap-popover-inside-viewport by @cvrebert.

Comment: I believe your code is missing an end span tag: </span>

Answer (score 290, accepted):

adding `.pull-right` to `ul.dropdown-menu` should do it

> **Deprecation Notice:** As of Bootstrap v3.1.0, `.pull-right` on dropdown menus is [deprecated](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment). To right-align a menu, use `.dropdown-menu-right`.

> **Deprecation Notice 2:** As of Bootstrap v5, `.dropdown-menu-right` is deprecated. For Bootstrap v5, use [`.dropdown-menu-end`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options).

Comment: That is a completely separate question

Comment: This answer does not actually fix the problem if user is using some smaller screen device -- it is going out of the left side in stead of right side (in fact that you just change the pull-left to the pull-right).

Comment: See krzychu answer as Bootstrap.pull-right is deprecated

Comment: @HristoEnev me either.  Did your dropdowns go way off the button?

Comment: With Boostrap v5.0, it's .dropdown-menu-end instead of .dropdown-menu-right

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options

Comment: Bootstrap 5.3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#directions

Answer (score 118):

Since Bootstrap v3.1.0 adding `.pull-right` is deprecated on dropdown menus. A `.dropdown-menu-right` should be added to `ul.dropdown-menu` instead. [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

Comment: Even with the latest bootstrap .pull-right works for me, and .dropdown-menu-right does nothing.

Comment: This does indeed work in Bootstrap 4, except you add the class .dropdown-menu-right to div.dropdown-menu (not ul)

Comment: `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">` worked for me on 4.1.1

Answer (score 27):

For Bootstrap 4, adding `dropdown-menu-right` works. Here's a working example..

http://codeply.com/go/w2MJngNkDQ

Comment: I tried all the other answers, - and this one was the only one that worked for me as well. I'm using Bootstrap v. 4.1.0.

Answer (score 22):

a solution that does not need modifying the HTML only the CSS is

```
li.dropdown:last-child .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

Its particularly usefull for dynamically generated menus where its not always possible to add the recommended class `dropdown-menu-right` to the last element

Comment: this is the only solution that works for bootstrap 4.0.0

Answer (score 12):

#### You can use class `.dropdown-pull-right` with following css:

```css
.dropdown-pull-right {
  float: right !important;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.dropdown-pull-right>.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown dropdown-pull-right btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  Open Dropdown
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

in Bootstrap 4 you can use .dropleft

just change to :

`<span class="dropleft">`

or

add .dropdown-menu-{lg,med,sm,xs}-right to your dropdown-menu

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm-right" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`float-*-right` for Bootstrap 4

`*` = xs, sm, md, lg

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment because my SO level is too low, but I just made sure that the parent container is set to "overflow:hidden" like so (also make sure position is set).

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">
    <span class="dropdown"> 
    <a href="#menu1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img class="left" src="/static/img/topmenu_preferences.png" /><b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5, according to documentation:

> Dropright:
> Trigger dropdown menus at the right of the elements by adding .dropend to the parent element.

```
<div class="btn-group dropend">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropright
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue recently, and I solved it by addind display="dynamic" to my ngbDropdown (using Angular 12, ngBootstrap 10 and Bootstrap 4):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div ngbDropdown display="dynamic" class="d-inline-block dropdown-menu-right">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="navbarDropdownForm" ngbDropdownToggle>Sign in</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownForm">
        <form class="px-4 py-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="navbarDropdownFormEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="navbarDropdownFormEmail" placeholder="email@example.com"
              autocomplete="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="navbarDropdownFormPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="navbarDropdownFormPassword" placeholder="Password"
              autocomplete="current-password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
              Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </form>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>New around here? Sign up</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Forgot password?</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```