# Why a dropdown list is going out of the window to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a drop down.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.Label("Project", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Label_small_bold" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ProjectID, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListProjects, "ID", "ProjectNo"), "-Select-", new { @class = "form-control  input-sm pull-right text-box single-line" })
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

It's good but when I get an item with long text then it goes out of the window to the right.

Why? 
[image]

Comment: You should post your select and option css classes, once you do it, you will notice your error... `text-box single-line` sounds as a prime suspect there.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806802/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-goes-outside-the-screen

Comment: @jmercier: I tried everything but not working

Comment: @skobaljic: tried but not working bro

Comment: Go to Firefox browser inspector > Style editor, there you can disable styles individually - click on eye icon, try to locate your problem. You can also inspect the option element and find out which selector defines its width... can't tell/help more, because you posted zero code in here.

Comment: adjust the width of dropdown menu and apply `word-break:break-word`

Comment: I am also having this problem.  I have tried every CSS attribute I can find.

Can anyone help on this?